# PHPMailer - Get errors by recipient

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer 6.6.5 and I am sending email to one recipient with multiple CC.

Some of these recipients are using an invalid email address, so the smtp server returns an error and PHPMailer is processing these as Exception. But the email was sent successfully to the recipients that was valid.

We need to identify when an error occurs which recipients will receive the email and which wont, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid email address"? Can you share the error message, along with the code you are currently using?

Comment: It does throw exceptions, but you can catch them and choose what to do in that situation.

Comment: The smtp server is returning a smto relay error because one of the email address does not exist. But some of the recipients are receiving it but, obviously not the one with an invalid email address